# How to adjust image dynamically with CSS for resizing of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I want my image to be a 'fixed height' on the page. i.e. 500px. but upon resizing the browser window, I want the image to adjust automatically (I guess by zooming in and out) so it remains proportional and not blurred.

I have this:

```css
.homepageheaderbox
{
height: 470px; 
width: 100%; 
margin-top:0%; 
padding-left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
margin-bottom: 0; 
margin-right: 0;
}
.homepageheaderbox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

```html
<div class="homepageheaderbox"><img style="margin-top:0%; 
padding-left: 0; 
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
margin-bottom: 0; 
margin-right: 0;" 
src="../Images/Homepage/RyanTeachesHome1.jpg"></div>
```

I know there is some unnecessary code here, I am still playing around with it.

Currently, the image resizes dynamically as the browser is resized, but the image height on the page changes also. To see more clearly what I am aiming to get, please visit: http://ryanteaches.com/ (<-- my target) and place it side by side with http://ryanteaches.com/newindex.html then readjust. You can visually see the difference.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this not being a comment (still not 50 rep),
I could recommend you looking at [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp) W3School's tutorial on responsive images. Or another solution for you is to use `@media` query in CSS [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Also here is the exact thing I believe you are asking for [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image_background1)

Comment: No - as question stated, I dont want the height of my image to change upon resizing. To maintain proportionality, I instead want the image to zoom in/out rather than heigh/width of it changing.

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you mean by the image to zoom in/out rather than width height changing. But maybe try the <code>@media</code> queries and then adjust your image based on screen size? Sorry if this was not helpful but I do not fully understand what you want to do. Hope this helps out anyway!

Comment: In question there is 2 links open them in separate windows and make them half screens each. You can then use centre window resizer to resize the windows. You will notice when resizing, on one of them (white nav bar) the image height is constant, the image zooms to maintain resolution. On the other (black nav bar) the image height adjusts with respect to width. Im trying to recreate the white nav bar version.

Comment: oh if you want your height property to be constant just use the `min-height` property to set the minimum height and then your image should not get lower than that. If you are facing issues maybe try and stick the `!important` just after the value. Example: `min-height: 400px !important;` hope this helps you out